# How to know if a time series is trending or mean reverting?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, trends, hurst-exponent

I came across Michael Halls-Moore [article on using the Hurst exponent test](https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Basics-of-Statistical-Mean-Reversion-Testing) to determine if a price time-series is mean-reverting, trend-following or closer to a random walk, but doesn't this disregard the fact that financial instruments often exhibit a "bid-ask bounce affect" ? In which case, is his approach of using the Hurst exponent a bit too naive to use in practice?

Are there other ways to determine if a price time-series is mean-reverting or trend following specifically for financial instruments that more applicable in real-world settings?

Answer (score 3):

The article that you linked mentioned several statistical tests, that approach the question from different angles. However, you should know that bid-ask bounce is not significant if you're looking at daily data on liquid (heavily traded) financial instruments.

Comment: What about intraday data, i.e. tick to tick data on fairly liquid instruments?